# Doesn't JavaScript button onClick event when you get a global variable?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, checkbox

I made a simple click event. But if I use js dom to make it a global variable, it doesn't seem to work. Is there a genius here who can explain the reason easily to me?

This is html file very very simple!

```
 <form>
      <input type="radio" name="a" id="ck1" /> 수신동의
      <input type="radio" name="a" id="ck2" /> 수신차단
      <input type="button" value="서비스 등록" onclick="checkHandle()" />
 </form>
```

This is JS file.

```
let ck1 = document.getElementById("ck1").checked;
let ck2 = document.getElementById("ck2").checked;
function checkHandle() {
  console.log(ck1);
  if (ck1 === false && ck2 === false) {
    alert("광고 수신 동의에 대해 선택해주세요.");
  } else {
    alert("서비스를 등록합니다.");
  }
}
```

or

```
function checkHandle() {
let ck1 = document.getElementById("ck1").checked;
let ck2 = document.getElementById("ck2").checked;
  console.log(ck1);
  if (ck1 === false && ck2 === false) {
    alert("광고 수신 동의에 대해 선택해주세요.");
  } else {
    alert("서비스를 등록합니다.");
  }
}
```

To be exact again what I want to say, I would like to ask you why declaring the ck1, ck2 variable declaration within the checkHandle function is different from declaring it as a global variable. Please explain it easily.

For your information, it didn't work properly when I declared it a global variable.

Comment: The first one is setting the variables to the states of the checkboxes when the page is first loaded. If the user checks and unchecks the boxes, the variables don't change.

Comment: The second one gets their state when the function is called.

Comment: Yes, you need to check the "state" of radio when you click the button and not save and store the initial state in global variable, which won't change when you actually toggle the radio buttons.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much 